# Clear a Map Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I just started learning javascript. Today trying to learn Map Object Key and Value Pairs. but somehow I see a nonfunctional method of Map namely clear().

whole code I posted below. and line34 and line36 prints same map pairs albeit map object clear method already invoked. where am I wrong ? I just wanna clear the Map object named list_
here is a link you can test and see weirdness: https://codepen.io/KTURKAY/pen/oEpXgb

```js
var list_ = new Map();

var inputkey;
var inputvalue;
var buttonadd;
var buttonclear;
var divlist;


function buttonclearclick(el, ev) {
  divlist.innerHTML = '';
  console.log(list_);
  list_.clear();//I expected, this method should clear it. but indeed it doesn't.?
  console.log(list_);
}

function buttonaddclick(c, e) {
  list_[inputkey.value] = inputvalue.value;
  divlist.innerHTML = "";

  for (x in list_) {
    let n = document.createElement('div');
    n.innerHTML = `${x} = ${list_[x]}`;
    divlist.appendChild(n);
  }
}

document.body.onload = function(ev) {
  inputkey = document.getElementById('inputkey');
  inputvalue = document.getElementById('inputvalue');
  buttonadd = document.getElementById('buttonadd');
  buttonclear = document.getElementById('buttonclear');
  divlist = document.getElementById('divlist');

  buttonadd.addEventListener('click', buttonaddclick);

  buttonclear.addEventListener('click', buttonclearclick);
}
```

```html
<form>
  KEY:
  <input type="text" id="inputkey" /> VALUE:
  <input type="text" id="inputvalue" />
  <input type="button" value="ADD" id="buttonadd" />
  <input type="button" value="CLEAR" id="buttonclear" />
</form>

<div id="divlist">
  NO DATA
</div>
```

Comment: This is just how `console.log` works. When you look at it, and open it in the console, you see the values as they are *now* (in their final state), not when you logged the map. To see this, try `console.log(list_.size)`.

Comment: console.log isn't matter. because as I press add button I still see old key-value pairs. (after clear method invoked)

Comment: You were overriding the `list_` content from a Map to an object because not using the prototype `Map` properly.

Comment: so what is the proper way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- The items are retrieved in the wrong way from the map. Use the `.get` method.
- The items are not iterated in the correct way. Use `for ... of` instead of `for ... in`

See updated script running correctly in this snippet. Comments indicate the corrections:

```js
var list_ = new Map();
var inputkey;
var inputvalue;
var buttonadd;
var buttonclear;
var divlist;

function buttonclearclick(el, ev) {
    divlist.innerHTML = '';
    console.log('before: ' + list_.size); // To make it work in this snippet
    list_.clear();
    console.log('after: ' + list_.size); // To make it work in this snippet
}

function buttonaddclick(c, e) {
    list_.set(inputkey.value, inputvalue.value); // Use set
    divlist.innerHTML = "";

    for (const [key, value] of list_) { // Get entries using `of`
        const n = document.createElement('div');
        n.textContent = `${key} = ${value}`; // Use pair coming from iterator
        divlist.appendChild(n);
    }
}

document.body.onload = function (ev) {
    inputkey = document.getElementById('inputkey');
    inputvalue = document.getElementById('inputvalue');
    buttonadd = document.getElementById('buttonadd');
    buttonclear = document.getElementById('buttonclear');
    divlist = document.getElementById('divlist');

    buttonadd.addEventListener('click', buttonaddclick);
    buttonclear.addEventListener('click', buttonclearclick);
}
```

```html
<form>
    KEY:
    <input type="text" id="inputkey" /> VALUE:
    <input type="text" id="inputvalue" />
    <input type="button" value="ADD" id="buttonadd" />
    <input type="button" value="CLEAR" id="buttonclear" />
</form>

<div id="divlist">
    NO DATA
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
  list_[inputkey.value] = inputvalue.value;
```

You need to use `get` and `set` to work with Maps:

```
 list_.set(inputkey.value, inputvalue.value);
```

Calling `clear()` does remove all key/values from the internal Maps Hashmap, but it does not clear the object properties. And if you use the first way of setting properties, you dont actually need a Map but you can use a plain object.

Comment: replacing that line did not solve. but also now adds nothing.
https://codepen.io/KTURKAY/pen/oEpXgb

Comment: @KursatTurkay You switched to store items in the map using `list_.set`, but you're still doing `list_[x]` instead of `list_.get(x)` to access the values of the map. You need to use both `set` and `get`. Map items do not exist as properties accessible via square-bracket access.

Comment: no luck. I used only get and set. and add button just adding nothing. here is modified one headed as you mentioned about
https://codepen.io/KTURKAY/pen/gvopze